# Mac OS X (Lion) Chrome: shortcut for "Search With Google"

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

Under **Keyboard Shortcuts : Application Shortcuts** I've already tried with either "**Search With Google**" or "**Google Search...**" as the **Menu Item** (both of these for **Application** set as **Google Chrome**, of course).

Also, even with Chrome as the default browser, the **Search With Google** (under **Services : Searching**; which works) always uses Safari.

In short, how do you set up a keyboard shortcut to avoid right-clicking the selected word and choosing **Search Google for 'the selected word'** from the right-click menu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The Search With Google service is provided by Safari, and it is not meant to work with other browsers.

You can create another service yourself though:

1. Open Automator and choose the Service template
2. Add a Run Shell Script action for a script like `open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"`
3. Save the service and assign it a shortcut from System Preferences

[image]

Comment: Lri, this is great; it works! Now, would you care to explain _how_ approximately it works? It invokes `bash`, then ... what does `ruby -e 'require "cgi"; print CGI.escape($<.read.chomp)'` do? I presume this returns back to Chrome?

Comment: @courteous The `ruby` command reads the string you searched for and [URL-escapes it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_escape). The result of this is evaluated by `$()` and just appended to the Google.com line by bash.

Comment: @slhck, thank you for the clarification. I'd up-vote if only I could.

Comment: @Lri THANKS FOR THAT! If somebody would like to have easy google translator access under right mouse button on OS X https://gist.github.com/andilab/7219174

Comment: You can also remove the stock one by finding if accord to the instructions at http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/14/remove-services-contextual-menu-mac-os-x/

Comment: @slhck - how do I add quotes around the search string (e.g. search for "hello world" rather than hello world)? I have tried to add " in several locations in this command but I only end up with one " in the search string, either in the beginning or at the end.

Comment: @d-b Can't confirm, it works for me when I add double quotes.

Comment: @slhck Where do you add the double quotes? Can you post your oneliner?

Comment: @d-b I just run `open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"`, then enter `"Hello World"`, then press `Ctrl-D`. `https://www.google.com/search?q="Hello+World"` opens.

Comment: @slhck Aah, but that requires that the search phrase contains double quotes in itself. I want to select a couple of words that is not quoted (company names in fact) and search for them at Google within quotes. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: More screenshots of how to create and connect the service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935301/how-to-force-mac-os-to-open-search-with-google-in-chrome

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays you can also use "Run Javascript" in automator services, and stack it with "Internet" → "Open webpages". Something like this:

JavaScript to run:

```
function run(input, parameters) {
   return "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(input)
}
```

Screenshot of Automator "service":
[image: screenshot of Automator "service"]

Comment: These days (2018) this is by far the best answer.

Comment: On my mac, Automator's Service has been changed to 'Quick Action'. And 'Run JavaScript' is under 'Utilities' on the left panel.

Comment: `"There was a problem with the input to the service"` in Preview.app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127041/automator-workflow-to-search-selection-there-was-a-problem-with-the-input-to works in other apps

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to add that if you use accepted answer and save the service as "**Search with Google**", it will be executed instead of the service of the same name that launches Safari.

Comment: That added a second "Search with Google" command to the context menu until I unchecked the one in Preferences - Keyboard - Services - Searching.

Comment: As of macOS Monterey 12.5.1, the name has changed to "Search With Google" (note the capital W). If you spell it this way, then @drstrangepork's suggestion works.