# Mac OS X (Lion) Chrome: keyboard shortcut for “Go to http://...”

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

As an extension of [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google), how would one add a keyboard shortcut for right-clicking a URL and selecting "**Go to http:// ...**" in Chrome?

Could it be done using the *same* shortcut as in the [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google) (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)? Say, by adding some reg-exp for "**http://**"?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please clarify, do you want a new entry in the context menu of a URL that opens the selected URL in Chrome?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm looking for a **keyboard** shortcut, so as to avoid right-clicking some-selected-URL and choosing `Go to http://selected.site.com`. Analogous to what Lri managed in [my previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You only want that in Chrome, or in any application?

Comment: @DanielBeck Only in Chrome (for avoiding any potential conflicts, I guess). I'm fairly new to OSx, so any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the Search With Google service, Open URL actually works with other browsers than Safari.

[image]

---

#### A service that opens a URL or a Google search page

[image]

```
input="$(cat)"
input="${input%\n}" # remove a possible trailing newline
if [[ "$input" =~ '://' ]]; then
    open "$input"
else
    open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$(echo -En "$input" |
    ruby -e 'require "cgi"; print CGI.escape($<.read.chomp)')"
fi
```

Comment: Lri, thank you once again. The extension of your Bash script from the previous question did the trick (that is, it uses a single shortcut). (I'd also vote-up, if only I had 15 reputation points.)

Comment: My system already had an "Open URL" service, and I've confirmed that I can use it to open a url that's selected from a text window. There's no shortcut, so I set the shortcut to be ⌘⇧U. But when I try the shortcut, I only hear the "thump" sound. Is there something else I need to do to make the shortcut become active?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's AppleScript API makes this task non-obvious, so I'll stick to the basics, once again using *Automator*:

[image]

```
for f in "$@"
do
    if [[ "${f:0:7}" != "http://" && "${f:0:8}" != "https://" ]] ; then
        f="http://$f"
    fi
    open -a "Google Chrome" "$f"
done
```

There's some rudimentary logic that makes e.g. "example.org" into a proper URL with `http://` scheme.

---

Since you also want the *scope* to be different (*all applications* vs. *just Chrome*) it's not possible to limit it to a single keyboard shortcut. Just assign a different one for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'll have to go with Lri's more complete answer (which uses a single shortcut).