# OS X Automator Shell Script for custom search with special character not encoded with utf-8

Tags: macos, shell, ruby, automator

I find a script here

[Mac OS X (Lion) Chrome: shortcut for "Search With Google"](https://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google)

which shows how to do google search using shell script in OS X Automator.

The original script is:

```
open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"
```

I am trying to adapt this script to a custom search for Chinese characters encoded in "gb2312".

Currently my script goes like:

```
open "http://www.yueyv.cn/index.asp?keyword=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp.encode("gb2312")')"
```

It works fine in terminal. For example, if testing with character "一", the script opens http://www.yueyv.cn/index.asp?keyword=%D2%BB/

However when adding this script as a service in OS X automator, it opens http://www.yueyv.cn/index.asp?keyword=/

The code of "一" is gone.

I've googled for quite a while without a result. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal sets `LANG` to a value like `en_US.UTF-8` by default if you haven't unchecked "Set locale environment variables on startup". Automator doesn't, so the ruby command results in an invalid byte sequence error.

```
$ unset LANG
$ echo 一|ruby -rcgi -e 'puts CGI.escape $<.read.chomp.encode("gb2312")'
-e:1:in `encode': "\xE4" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
$ echo 一|LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 ruby -rcgi -e 'puts CGI.escape $<.read.chomp.encode("gb2312")'
%D2%BB
```

Try to use `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 ruby`. Or replace the ruby command with `iconv -f utf-8 -t gb2312|xxd -p|tr -d \\n|sed 's/../%&/g'`.

Comment: It works perfectly! It is the second time your answer helps me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I realize you put "tr -d \\n" command in order to get rid of new line character in the string and dump the "0a" in the hex output. I think it should be placed after the string like this:"string"|tr -d \\n|iconv -f utf-8 -t gb2312|xxd -p|sed 's/../%&/g'

Comment: No, `tr -d \\n` is meant to remove linefeeds from the output of `xxd -p` (which prints 60 characters per line). You can use `printf %s "$(cat)"` to remove a linefeed from the end of the input. Or replace `echo` with `printf %s`.