# Cannot delete the original service in context menu and replace it with a user-generated one

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I created a user-defined service called "search with Google" that open in Chrome instead of Safari. But I can't delete the original one even though I have deselected it in System Preference.
Edit: Note that I am not asking how to create a user defined service, which I have already done. I am however unable to delete the original one even though I have deselected it in the service shortcut. 
[image]»
[image]
system: macOS Mojave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS X (Lion) Chrome: shortcut for "Search With Google"](https://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google)

Comment: Have you tried restart? I have seen (once) shortcuts and related services behaving differently after some time/ restart.

Comment: Thanks. restart doesn't work for me, unfortunately.